# Why am I getting the Segmentation fault (core dumped) error in my program when using 2d arrays?

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to create Conway's Game of Life in c++ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) and I have no idea as to why it throws this error. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void Life() {
    //initializing all the variables needed
    int creatures;
    int row;
    int column;
    int neighbors = 0;
    int days = 0;
    char cont = 'c';
    //creates Board
    string Board[20][20];
    string NewBoard[20][20];
    //stores X for dead into all elements
    for (int r = 0; r <= 19; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c <= 19; c++) {
            Board[r][c] = "X ";
        }
    }
    //asks for and stores the users coords
    cout<<"Enter the amount of creatures desired: ";
    cin>>creatures;
        for (int i = 0; i <= creatures - 1; i++) {
            cout<<"\nEnter the row of the next creature: ";
            cin>>row;
            cout<<"\nEnter the column of the next creature: ";
            cin>>column;
            Board[row - 1][column - 1] = "O ";
        }
    for (int r = 0; r <= 19; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c <= 19; c++) {
            NewBoard[r][c] = Board[r][c];
        }
    }

    while (cont == 'c') {
        for (int r = 0; r <= 19; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c <= 19; c++) {
                Board[r][c] = NewBoard[r][c];
            }
        }
        cout<<"\n\n\n\nDay "<<days<<"\n";
        //prints current board
        for (int r = 0; r <= 19; r++) {
            cout<<"\n";
            for (int c = 0; c <= 19; c++) {
                cout<<Board[r][c];
        }
    }
        cout<<"\n\n";
        //detects for alive creatures then checks them for neighbors
        for (int r = 0; r <= 19; r++) {

            for (int c = 0; c <= 19; c++) {
                //detects for life
                if (Board[r][c] == "O ") {
                    //detects for neighbors
                    neighbors = 0;
                    if (Board[r + 1][c + 1] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r + 1][c] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r + 1][c - 1] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r][c + 1] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r][c - 1] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r - 1][c + 1] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r - 1][c] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r - 1][c - 1] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    //kills the creature if it has less than 2 or more than 3 living neighbors
                    if (neighbors < 2) {
                        NewBoard[r][c] = "X ";
                    }
                }
                //if creature is dead, checks to see how many live neighbors
                else {
                    neighbors = 0;
                    if (Board[r + 1][c + 1] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r + 1][c] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r + 1][c - 1] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r][c + 1] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r][c - 1] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r - 1][c + 1] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r - 1][c] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (Board[r - 1][c - 1] == "O ") {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    //"resurrects" creature if it has 3 neighbors
                    if (neighbors == 3) {
                        NewBoard[r][c] = "O ";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //asks if user wants to continue
        cout<<"\n\nPress c to continue, q to quit: ";
        cin>>cont;
        days++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Life();
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if it's really hard to read (I'm still learning). I've concluded that the problem comes from the else part of the while loop. Why is this?

Comment: It would be far better if you switched to `vector<T>` and used `at()` for element access. This will likely convert your seg fault into an exception at the proper point. Also you'll need to learn debugging on your own.

Comment: Also imagine what happens when this executes `if (Board[r + 1][c - 1] == "O ") ` for `c == 0`. You are trying to access column# -1 there.

Comment: Which ide are you using and what os are you on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    for (int r = 0; r <= 19; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c <= 19; c++) {
```

Inside this loop you will have both `r` and `c` cover the entire range of 0-19.

```
                if (Board[r + 1][c + 1] == "O ") {
                    neighbors++;
                }
```

When either `r` or `c` is 19, here, this is going to attempt to access either `Board[20][something]` or `Board[something][20]`, which, of course, does not exist. Undefined behavior. Crash.

```
                if (Board[r - 1][c - 1] == "O ") {
                    neighbors++;
                }
```

Similarly, when either `r` or `c` is 0, this will attempt to access a negative array index. Undefined behavior. Crash.

The above are just an example of a common defect that nearly all of your `if` statements suffer: lack of proper bounds checking.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, it still crashes when r and c are not 0 or 19. Does it crash from the possibility that r or c might be an "unacceptable" value? Also, what might you suggest as a solution?

Comment: A simple inspection of your code shows that the very first iteration of the loop, when `r` and `c` are both 0, is guaranteed to result in out of bounds access on at least one `if` statement. That immediately voids your warranty. Even if the code limps along, and eventually blows up a few iterations down the road, well, your warranty has been voided. This is what "undefined behavior" means. As far as a solution: implement proper bounds checking. Do not access the array directly, but pass all coordinates to a function that returns a default value if either row or column is out of bounds.

Comment: Hemil thank you for your concern but yes I do understand what he said.